# Multiple Chrome Threads But Low CPU Used, how to allow chrome using more cpu?

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, vps, threads, bots

I'm using an AMD EPYC 7502P 32c/64t.

I'm running a bot that opens multiple Chrome instances. I'm running over 200 threads. For some reason, I'm using only 20% of the CPU power.

Chrome is not really running well. A few tabs are stuck and I'm getting errors in the bot.

In another case, I have another VPS 6c/12t (ryzen5 3600) running 60 threads without any problem - CPU 80%.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A program can not "automatically" scale to use multiple cores in parallel. This is especially true with languages like JavaScript, that are principally single-threaded.

In addition to that, raw processing power is not the only resource needed: You need I/O (network speed and storage performance). If chrome is actually stuck, this is very often more of a disk issue than of a CPU issue.

Chrome is designed and built to be used by a human - this implies assumptions such as a sane maximum number of user inputs per time unit. Your bot might just run afoul of these.

Comment: i dont think its the disk mate, im using only 10-20 mb/sec  https://prnt.sc/tqgioo    im using SSD.